# Access Denied when calling SharePoint Import-SPWeb cmdlet remotely

Tags: powershell, sharepoint, import, sharepoint-2013

I am currently trying to import a SharePoint 2013 site into a single server farm via the Import-SPWeb PowerShell cmdlet. It is a pretty straightforward process, except the twist is that I need to do it remotely from another machine by using Invoke-Command. This remote machine calls Invoke-Command and invokes the following script on the SharePoint server, which I called SPOINT13SSS.

Below you will find the content of both the call and the script.

CALL (from remote machine to SPOINT13SSS):

```
Invoke-Command -ComputerName SPOINT13SSS.sandbox.local -Authentication CredSSP -Credential $spusercreds[0] -ArgumentList "SPOINT13SSS" -FilePath C:\Users\rsmith\Desktop\SPScripts\Framework\Create\Create_SPSite.ps1
```

SCRIPT:

```
$spserver = $args[0]

Add-PSSnapin Microsoft.SharePoint.Powershell

Write-Host "[INFO] SP Server is $spserver"
Write-Host "[INFO] Beginning Import of the Site Collection into SharePoint for testing..."

try{Import-SPWeb http://$spserver -Path C:\SP13Install\siteexport.cmp -UpdateVersions Overwrite}
catch{Write-Error "[ERROR] Importing the Site Collection failed. Please make sure that the siteexport.cmp file exists and that you have proper access permissions to both the file and the SharePoint database."}
```

The issue I'm having - When I run

```
Import-SPWeb http://$spserver -Path C:\SP13Install\siteexport.cmp -UpdateVersions Overwrite
```

on SPOINT13SSS, the import works just fine, no flaws.

When I run it remotely, however, I get the following error:

```
Access is denied. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070005 (E_ACCESSDENIED))
+ CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (Microsoft.Share...CmdletImportWeb:SPCmdletImportWeb) [Import-SPWeb], UnauthorizedAccessException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell.SPCmdletImportWeb
+ PSComputerName        : SPOINT13SSS.sandbox.local
```

I have made sure that the user I am authenticating with via CredSSP has the following privileges:

- Farm Administrator
- Site Collection Administrator
- Local Administrator on SPOINT13SSS

I am also 100% sure that the credentials are correct because I have other scripts called via Invoke-Command with this PSCredential and they work fine.

In addition, I have also tried fiddling with the NTFS Permissions on *C:\SP13Install\siteexport.cmp* (Everyone - Access Full control) and can't seem to get this to work. I also attempted to share the folder. I can access it from the remote machine, read and write to it, but I just can't Invoke this command from the remote machine to SPOINT13SSS.

Comment: I solved the issue by assigning the account as the service account for the web application pool where the site collection resides and resetting IIS via iisreset /noforce.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the issue by assigning the account as the service account for the web application pool where the site collection resides and resetting IIS via iisreset /noforce